# Clustering using using min,max,mean and standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, euclidean, extreme-value

I have read some papers on `clustering` application to detect `outliers` in the data set. In many places the `euclidean distance` between any 2 data points is calculated using `minimum` , `maximum` , `mean` and `standard deviation` of the data unit. Let's say the data set consists of multiple samples each of 1 hour duration. Now 1 hour of data is summarized to `minimum` , `maximum` , `mean` and `standard deviation` and `euclidean distance` is calculated on these parameters.
My doubt is what is the **significance and rationale** behind selecting the above 4 descriptive statistical parameters for subsequent use in clustering application.

Comment: Could you add a reference? This practice is non standard, though to be clear any distance metric can be used

Comment: I have never heard of using min, max, mean & SD to calculate Euclidean distance, & I cannot see how it is possible. The Euclidean distance between 2 points is the square root of the sum of the squared distances on each dimension. Can you say more about your situation & your data?

Comment: @Harsh and @gung   It was used like `d(X,Y) = sqrt( (avgx  -  avgy  )^2 + (stdx  -  stdy  )^2 + (maxx  -  maxy  )^2 + (minx  -  miny  )^2`

Comment: @Harsh  [ http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/MSPOPS12 ] Here you can find the paper _**"New Telemetry Monitoring Paradigm with Novelty Detection"_**

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can also add other moments such as kurtosis and skew. In essence, this is the approach to clustering time series suggested by Rob Hyndman in this paper, *Dimension Reduction for Clustering Time Series Using Global Characteristics* where he develops the rationale.

http://www.robjhyndman.com/papers/wang2.pdf

Comment: @Johnson  Thanks for the reference. But the rationale for selecting _"`min,max,mean and std deviation`"_ is not mentioned in the paper.

Comment: "Moments" refer to key statistics of any distribution, even if the metrics you're focused on aren't explicitly mentioned.